# Why doesn't VS Code/TypeScript recognize the indices property on the result of Regex.exec?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

**TL;DR:** This compiles now. See the update below.

If you look this [`exec` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#description), it says a property should exist called `indices`:

> An array where each entry represents a substring match. Each substring match itself is an array where the first entry represents its start index and the second entry its end index.
> The indices array additionally has a groups property which holds an object of all named capturing groups. The keys are the names of the capturing groups and each value is an array with the first item being the start entry and the second entry being the end index of the capturing group. If the regular expression doesn't contain any capturing groups, groups is undefined.

[Here is my code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/AQ4KFUGMHsDsDOAXYBTAHsAvMA9MACgG0BDAWgC8BdASlwBMBzAOg1SgIklACITgARsCjB6aYADMeXSDQDcM0AEsJhDDWABvRZFiIUmHBmZK49JVFQIF3YAF8gA):

```
  const ex = / ([a-z])/dg.exec(
    "a b c d e f"
  );
  if (ex) {
    const x = ex.indices; // Error! Property 'indices' does not exist on type 'RegExpExecArray'.
  }
```

I kind of feel like I'm missing something really obvious. Why doesn't this compile and how do I get it to?

### Update

[My original code errored](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.9.5#code/AQ4KFUGMHsDsDOAXYBTAHsAvMA9MACgG0BDAWgC8BdASlwBMBzAOg1SgIklACITgARsCjB6aYADMeXSDQDcM0AEsJhDDWABvRZFiIUmHBmZK49JVFQIF3YAF8gA), but it doesn't error in TypeScript v5.x.x. The above "Here is my code" link always uses the latest compiler, and if you click it, you'll note there is no compile error (anymore).

Comment: Why do you expect the `indices` property to be set?

Comment: Yea me too, I pasted it into the Node command line and it worked.

Comment: Are you all trying JavaScript or TypeScript? You can click on my second link and see an error, right?

Comment: Typescript **is** JavaScript. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proposal that added `.indicies` is [pretty new](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-match-indices) - it only advanced to Stage 4 in the TC39 process less than a year ago, and TypeScript hasn't integrated it yet. There [is an open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44227) on the TS github to add `.indicies`, but it hasn't been fixed yet.

In short, if you want this to *just work*, you'll have to wait until someone contributes this new feature to TypeScript typings.

You could, of course, define a type yourself, and use `as` to assert:

```
type RegExpMatchArrayWithIndices = RegExpMatchArray & { indices: Array<[number, number]> };

const ex = / ([a-z])/dg.exec(
    "a b c d e f"
);
if (ex) {
    const x = (ex as RegExpMatchArrayWithIndices).indices;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a stupid question, but will this *run* correctly if I cast it to any?

Comment: It could, if it doesn't run afoul of your linter, but I'd really recommend avoiding `any`, since that basically defeats the purpose of TypeScript. You can create a new type with the `indices` property, then assert that the match is of that new type.

Comment: Just FYI, `indices` could have `groups` on it, too, but I understand your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Corrected: type RegExpMatchArrayWithIndices = RegExpMatchArray & { indices: [number, number] & { groups: { [key: string]: [number, number] } } };

Comment: The error goes away if you modify `lib` to use `ES2022` in `tsconfig.json`